# Redux store shows the same state twice, in different reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

Redux DevTools shows the same state for two different reducers

I am trying to add a second reducer in my React project using Redux to bring some overview of my state.  Whenever I view the state in Redux DevTools I see the same state but under different reducers.

The DevTools plugins show the content of the plannerSlice.js (createDialogOpen & editDialogOpen) both in the generalSlice and also in plannerSlice.

How can I get `darkTheme` under my generalSlice in the devTools?

Store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import generalSlice from "./slicers/plannerSlice";
import plannerSlice from "./slicers/plannerSlice";

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    general: generalSlice,
    planner: plannerSlice,
  },
});
```

generalSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const generalSlice = createSlice({
  name: "general",
  initialState: {
    appTheme: "dark",
  },
  reducers: {
    appTheme: (state) => {
      if (state.appTheme === "dark") {
        state.appTheme = "light";
      } else {
      state.appTheme = "light";
      }
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { appTheme } = generalSlice.actions;

export default generalSlice.reducer;
```

plannerSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const plannerSlice = createSlice({
  name: "planner",
  initialState: {
    createDialogOpen: false,
    editDialogOpen: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    createDialogOpen: (state, action) => {
      state.createDialogOpen = action.payload;
    },
    editDialogOpen: (state, action) => {
      state.editDialogOpen = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
export const { createDialogOpen, editDialogOpen } = plannerSlice.actions;

export default plannerSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 2):

As I just read my question once more, I noticed that I import the same slice twice... Just under a different name.

Store.js

```
import generalSlice from "./slicers/plannerSlice";
import plannerSlice from "./slicers/plannerSlice";
```

Comment: `import generalSlice from "./slicers/GeneralSlice";` should do the trick